# OWA Rules: Error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: identity"

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-app

I am seeing this error show up lots on SO but nothing that pertains to this specific issue. All I am trying to do is set up a server-side rule that takes all messages in a specific 'Group' and applies a category. If I select someone FROM the Group, no problem. But if I select the Group itself (which the system allows me to do), when I try to save, I get this error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: identity." Any thoughts on what is causing this? If it allows me to select the Group and build the rest of the rule, it seems to me that it is allowable but the save throws the error. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hello. I tested this on another machine with a different Exchange Hosting service and same problem ... doesn't any one have some thoughts on this problem? I can't be the only person wanting server-side rules who has run into this?

Comment: I am facing this same issue in MS Outlook web.